# Remove edit post link from static front page

Tags: frontpage

Checking for front page with either is_home() or is_front_page() still removes the edit link from all pages/posts. What's wrong with this?

```
add_filter( 'edit_post_link', 'foo_edit_post_link' );

function foo_edit_post_link() {

  if (is_home()) {
   return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function foo_edit_post_link($link) {
  if (is_home()) {
   return FALSE;
  }
    return $link;
}
```

Comment: Almost. Had to also change the homepage check to if(is_home() || is_front_page()).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a custom template why not just remove the_loop from your template?